# Reusing previously instantiated templates with ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I have a need for a `<select>` on a form to control the remaining available inputs. This is achieved easily with angular by binding the `<select>` to the src of an `ng-include`.

The problem is each time the user changes the selected value (and hence the `src` template), angular compiles the template from scratch and attaches a new scope. This has the effect of wiping all the input data each time. The user expects if they change back to a previously selected option, all the field data they previously entered will still be there.

Is there any built in way to achieve the desired behaviour? Ideally an option so that the `ng-include` will re-use a previously compiled template and associated scope?

One workaround is to `ng-include` all the templates, and use `ng-show` to only display the current one. This seems heavy though, there is a lot of DOM elements on the page unnecessarily. (Especially for my use-case where there will be about ~20 different templates, and this whole `<select>` element and dynamic template control may be repeated on a single page up to 40 times.)

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wjtx3md3/1/). The desired outcome is the counter on template 1 is persisted when changing the dropdown to template 2 and back to 1.

Comment: Store each ngInclude form view information into a factory. It will persist regardless of what template is currently loaded.

Comment: Why not use a service that stores the values and handles them across the different templates?

Answer (score 1):

I found this question interesting.  Short of putting the model in a service (which is probably the correct way), I don't think there is a built in way to cache templates with ng-include without using ng-repeat, as demonstrated [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wjtx3md3/2/).

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <select ng-model="template" ng-options="t.name for t in templates">
     <option value="">(blank)</option>
    </select>
    url of the template: <tt>{{template.url}}</tt>
    <hr/>
    <div ng-repeat="t in templates" ng-include="t.url" ng-show="template.name == t.name">
     </div>
  </div>
```

As you point out, the downside of this solution is you end up with a lot of elements in the DOM.

For fun, I wrote a version of ng-include that caches the template element and reuses it.  You still end up potentially creating just as many DOM nodes in the worst case, but since they are created only on-demand, and since only one is ever in the DOM at any given time, it should remain fairly efficient from an angular perspective.

[Here is the fiddle for this directive](http://jsfiddle.net/wjtx3md3/4/).

```
.directive('cacheInclude', function ($compile, $http, $templateCache) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            var cache = {};
            var currentElement = element;
            var replaceCurrent = function(cacheEntry) {

                currentElement.replaceWith(cacheEntry);
                currentElement = cacheEntry;
            };
            scope.$watch(function(){
                return scope.$eval(attrs.src);
            }, function () {
                var src = scope.$eval(attrs.src);

                if (!cache[src]) {
                    $http.get(src, {cache: $templateCache}).then(function (result) {


                        cache[src] = $compile(result.data.trim())(scope.$new());
                        replaceCurrent(cache[src]);
                    });
                } else {

                    replaceCurrent(cache[src]);
                }
            });
        }
    }
})
```

It's not "built in", but I think it is a good middle ground solution.  Note, the directive is "for example only" and still requires error handling, etc.

Comment: Thanks Joe! Your `cacheInclude` directive is exactly what I was planning to attempt to write if there was no built in way to do it. Unfortunately it doesn't fully work, while the DOM elements get cached, the bindings seem to have been lost. e.g. the + button click no longer calls the `inc()` function on the controller after re-selecting template1.

Comment: I can't work out why either. I thought maybe the scope was being destroyed as a side effect of `currentElement.replaceWith(cacheEntry);` but it doesn't seem to be - there is no `$destroy` event raised. And I confirmed that it does get raised in the normal case - try changing the `cache-include` back to the normal `ng-include` in this fiddle and you can see the event in action: http://jsfiddle.net/wjtx3md3/8/

Comment: Ok, some weird findings here. Looks like the bindings aren't completely lost, just the button's `ng-click` handlers. In this fiddle the content binding `{{myContent}}` still works, while the button's click does not: http://jsfiddle.net/sxm22w3b/1/

Any ideas? I'm completely stumped.

Comment: My guess is that you need to use detach and append rather than replaceWith.

Comment: I was just playing with that :) http://jsfiddle.net/sxm22w3b/17/ And you're 100% correct, `replaceWith` strips the event handlers, `detach` doesn't. Thanks again Joe!

Comment: Glad to help! currentElement.before( cacheEntry ).detach() would be better for multi element scenarios.