# ng-click binding lost if DOM element removed and re-added

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a need to re-add previously compiled angular html back into the DOM tree after it has been removed ([see here for background reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654061/reusing-previously-instantiated-templates-with-ng-include)).

Content bindings still work as expected. e.g. when a scope variable changes, any `{{someVariable}}` bindings update with the new value.

However `ng-click` bindings stop working. The associated function on the controller just stops being called.

[See this fiddle for repro](http://jsfiddle.net/sxm22w3b/2/). Clicking the + button initially, you will see the counter increment. But after clicking Toggle twice, the + button no longer works, however the {{count}} binding still updates.

Please ignore the DOM manipulation within the controller. It is just to simplify the repro. You would normally do this within a directive. See [my original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654061/reusing-previously-instantiated-templates-with-ng-include) and [Joe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28654788/505457) for a more realistic implementation.

Answer (score 3):

I havn't used jquery in so long I forgot about some of the gotchas.

> The .detach() method is the same as .remove(), except that .detach() keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the DOM at a later time.

http://api.jquery.com/detach/

And of course angular's jqlite follows the same conventions. So the call to `replaceWith` removes the event handlers that were attached by `ng-click`. Instead, using `detach` and `append` retains the event handlers, and everything works as expected:

http://jsfiddle.net/sxm22w3b/17/

Comment: Didn't think of a jQuery solution - went straight into Angular :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to recompile it first with the scope it needs.

Please see here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/andyw_/72NYm/

I compile the template first before inserting it in this line here:

```
var targetFn = $compile(target);
```

You can refer to the docs for more information - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler#how-directives-are-compiled

Comment: Wow, I didn't know you could re-compile an existing DOM element like that (I thought it was only for html strings and template files). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use detach().

```
  old.before( new ).detach()
```

is the equivalent to replaceWith()

;)

Comment: hahaha, and you timed it just as I posted my own answer too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following solution:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <button ng-click="toggle()">Toggle</button>
    <div ng-show="showContent" id="toggleTarget">
        Some content = {{myContent}}
        <button ng-click="inc()">+</button>
    </div>
    <div id="placeholder" ng-show="showplaceholder">Placeholder</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function Ctrl($rootScope, $scope, $element) {
    $scope.myContent = 1;

    var target = angular.element(document.getElementById("toggleTarget"));
    var placeholder = angular.element(document.getElementById("placeholder"));

    var removed = false;
    $scope.showContent = true;
    $scope.placeholder = false;

    $scope.toggle = function(){
        $scope.myContent += 1;

        if (removed) {
            $scope.showContent = true;
            $scope.placeholder = false;
            removed = false;
        }
        else {
            $scope.showContent = false;
            $scope.placeholder = true;
            removed = true;
        }    
    }

    $scope.inc = function(){
        $scope.myContent += 1;
    };
}

angular.module('app', []);
```

Above code gives the respective output. Please check this code and mark as useful if you are getting the output as you want.